# Get lines in Adapter

Tags: android

I have ArrayAdapter for my ListView. It have TextView and arrow image. If TextView have 3 lines or more I must show arrow image, but if lines count < 3 arrow must be hidden.
But in fact Adapter doesn't have their lines count when before TextView will be draw. Any ideas? I need show item with arrow or not, depends on lines count.

This code not work (TextView receive line count only after drawing)

```
if(holder.text.getLineCount() < 3)
{
        holder.arrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
        holder.arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delay the execution of your code until after the text has been updated. Try using the [TextView::addTextChangedListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) event for this:

```
holder.text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable target) {

        if(holder.text.getLineCount() < 3) {
             holder.arrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
             holder.arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Comment: Not work. Show arrow even we have 1 or 2 lines( And hide all arrows after updating ListView